# Simplest video format

Tags: java

I am creating a program in java that involves writing videos from an array of buffered images. I was wondering what the simplest image format to use from java is that i could use to create a video.  I noticed the JMF but that looked complicated and not something that i would like to use if i can avoid it.  I don't want to use any external libraries because i don't want to deal with licenses.  Currently i don't care about using inefficient means to obtain this goal.  If the format can support audio that would also.  Additionally, any tutorial or links would also be appreciated.

Comment: In principle, wouldn't this just be a matter of double buffering and displaying the images at so-and-so frames (probably around 24) per second? OpenGL could probably do this as well as handle the sound.

Comment: I'd probably aim for 15 frames a second -- should be sufficient in most cases.

Comment: Motion JPEG is the simplest video file format I can think of.  It has basically no compression ( besides the JPEGing of individual frames ) because it doesn't try to analyze interframe differences.  But even that relies on JPEG which is not an 'open' standard.  I think a lot of digital cameras use this for streaming data to memory card. Very simple computationally.

Comment: If you try to write the pixel buffers out raw, without even JPEGing them, you are going to have an enormous amount of data on your hands.